# Can I repair my own roof in MA

Tags: roofing

Can I as a homeowner in Mass pull a permit to repair my roof myself or do I need a contractor, I have a friend who does handy work but is not licensed can I still use him for the job.

Comment: Cannot speak specifically for MA (this site is not intended to be region specific in terms of Q&A) but generally you don't need a permit for roof repairs as its not new construction.

Comment: In some cases roof repairs involve plumbing vents, etc. For that reason you may need inspection for those trades.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because permits are off-topic

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo that statement may be true where you live, but it certainly isn’t true where I live.  Here, however, they seem to be more interested in the roofing material used than the quality of the job completed.  My area recently had severe hail damage to roofs, everyone nearby is getting new roofs—the city warned the day after the hail storm that roofing permits are required, yet all the inspector seems to want to verify is if approved materials were used, he didn’t climb a ladder during my inspection.

Comment: @Tyson that would be why I said "generally", yes.

Comment: So “generally speaking” the OP should contact the local building department and ask.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I don't think "generally" is even applicable since I know my area also requires permits for reroofing

Comment: https://www.trulia.com/voices/Home_Buying/What_happens_if_inspection_shows_roof_repair_but_-156503 <- source for 'generally' - YMMV

Answer (score 4):

Most areas allow the homeowner to perform your own work as long as you pull the proper permits and have it inspected.

Also, in my state, you have to sign an affidavit that you plan to live there for at least one year when you pull the permit.

However, every area has its own rules and the only way to know for sure is to check with your local Authority Having Jurisdiction.

Good luck!

Comment: In CA you can do any roof repair if it is 10% or less w/o permit.  Just FYI